# How can I pass jQuery Raty score to Wtforms or Flask or Python

Tags: jquery, python, flask, wtforms

Happy new year first.

I try to get jQuery Raty  score (Number type) with a wtforms form. But I finde no way to send the score number to my backend.

Blow is the key part of my html code:

```html
{% block content %}
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/jquery.raty.js"></script>
<link href="../static/css/jquery.raty.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">

<form method="POST" action="/test">
<div id="star"></div>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.rating.label }} 
 {{ form.rating(id ='result') }}
    <input type="submit" value="Go">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#star').raty({
            path:"../static/img",
   score: '#result',
   targetKeep      : true,  
        });
</script>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

And for the python part, I use this:

```py
class rating(Form):
rating = TextAreaField()

@app.route('/test',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    form = rating()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    stars = rating.data
    print stars
return render_template('test.html',form=form)
```

**So after I run my server and summit the star number, my python console only print

```
<property object at 0x00000000032DE408>
```

instead of the score number.**

Can anyone give me a hand, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It creates hidden input "score", you have to capture it in backend.

```
<input type="hidden" name="score" value="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

`rating` is your form class. `form` is your form instance.

```
stars = form.rating.data
```

If you're using Flask-WTF you can use the `validate_on_submit` shorthand.

```
if form.validate_on_submit()
    stars = form.rating.data
```